# Is there a panel to resize component automatically?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I want to create a window like this one :

[image: Window 1]

And if I close a component I want my component to resize like this :

[image: Window 2]

Is there a panel to do so, if no, how should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use any of the [built-in layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm), HBox, VBox, BorderPane, etc.; except AnchorPane or Pane, don't use those as those last two don't easily resize content. Choose the layout pane which best fits what you are trying to achieve.

Your resizable component will resize in most layouts. The purpose of a layout is to arrange contained components according to a layout type and constraints. For most layouts, this work includes resizing resizable components.

When you use the layout panes, understand that you might need to set additional constraints on your nodes to get them to resize as you would wish (e.g. [`VBox.setVgrow(childNode, Priority.ALWAYS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-)) and the childNode needs to be a resizable node.  Most [controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) or [regions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) are resizable and may be resized by layout managers; shapes like circles and rectangles are not resized by layout managers.  Resizable nodes will have a min/max/pref size settings to set the respective limits for resize bounds for the node.

Use the [scene builder 2 application](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) to create some layouts with constraints and experiment using the scene builder preview capability.